# Error:The following From address failed: (SugarCRM)

Tags: email, sugarcrm, outbound

i am currently a newbie trying to configure outbound email server for SugarCRM but when i enter "from" address and tap on send "testmail" and enter some email there, it give me following error:

> Error:The following From address failed:

Can anyone help me out with this error,i am not able to figure it out thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure that you have SSL and Imap modules installed on Apache. 
Second I have always configured my outgoing mail easily via Yahoo mail:

Switch to `other` tab:
Just edit `from name` `from address` `SMTP port` `SMTP server` `SMTP user name` `SMTP password`

[image]